# Find command doesn't work properly for a hidden folder

Tags: linux, bash, find

I have the following directory tree:

[image]

Inside the "all" folder there are a lot of subfolder, let's call one of them "mainfolder".

What I want to do is:

- to delete all files in the mainfolder which are older than 2 minutes **other than `mainfolder/.ssh` folder (and what is inside) and the `.sync` file**

I have the following find command:

```
find all/* -mindepth 1 ! \( -name ".sync" -o -type d,f -path all'/*/.ssh' -o -type d,f -path all'/*/.ssh/*' \) -mmin +2 -delete >/dev/null
```

It works so far, but the `mainfolder/test/.ssh` folder and the included files (file5 and .file6) won't be deleted:

[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you sure, that .file6 and file5 both haven't been modified during the past 2 minutes?

Comment: @user1934428

 Yes, they both haven't modified.

Comment: @oguz ismail doesn't work folder mainfolder/test/.ssh and files inside are still available

Comment: @oguzismail : I don't think that `-prune` would be a good idea. The file tree is processed depth-first anyway, so IMO the approach taken by the OP is basically correct.

Comment: For debugging, I would first replace the `--delete` by `--depth`. This should print all files/directories, which `find` would delete. If there still are some entries missing, your question boils down to "why doesn't `find` print those directories, which is slightly easier than the current question. In that case, I suggest that you run a `stat` on the problematic entries and post the output of this command.

Comment: Please [don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) Ginormous images like these are distracting because you have to scroll around a lot. (I have scaled them down somewhat.)

Answer (score 1):

`*` does not treat `/` specially.

One possibility is to double each test:

```
find all \
    -mindepth 2 \
    \( \
        -path 'all/*/.ssh' ! -path 'all/*/*/.ssh' -prune \
        -o \
        -path 'all/*/.sync' ! -path 'all/*/*/.sync' -prune \
        -o \
        ...
    \)
```

If you are using GNU grep, it may have `-regex`:

```
find all \
    -mindepth 2 \
    \( \
        -regextype awk \
        -regex 'all/[^/]+/\.(ssh|sync)' -prune \
        -o \
        ...
    \)
```

Answer (score 1):

As-is I get:

```
find: cannot delete ‘all/mainfolder/test’: Directory not empty
```

Replacing `-delete` with `-exec rm -fr {} +` works, though when `test` is >2m it's removed, regardless of age of files under it.

`-prune` doesn't work with `-delete`, so doesn't help by itself. Note that as jhnc mentioned, slashes *do not delimit the glob* in `-path 'all/*/.ssh'`, so the `*` matches `all/mainfolder/test/.ssh` as well - that's probably your issue. This might not be a one-liner; consider a script.

Expanding a bit on jhnc's regex-based idea, I'd recommend doing it in a couple of passes.

Starting with your example file structure -

```
$: find all
all/
all/mainfolder/
all/mainfolder/.file2
all/mainfolder/.ssh/
all/mainfolder/.ssh/authorized_keys
all/mainfolder/.ssh/id_rsa
all/mainfolder/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
all/mainfolder/.sync
all/mainfolder/file1
all/mainfolder/test/
all/mainfolder/test/.file4
all/mainfolder/test/.ssh/
all/mainfolder/test/.ssh/.file6
all/mainfolder/test/.ssh/file5
all/mainfolder/test/file3
```

I substituted in an `-exec rm {} +` for the `-delete`, which allows us to use `-prune` to skip files and directories. Borrowing jhnc's `-regex` prevents `-path` from ignoring slash delimiters, so it avoids an arbitrary depth issue.

I set `-type f` on this pass so that directories older than 2m won't be deleted even if files in them *don't* match, which would eliminate files it shouldn't. That also saves us from having to use a `-r`ecursive option to `rm` for some added safety (for the same reason). For this example we didn't need the `-mindepth` so I removed it.

```
$: find all -mmin +2 -type f -regextype awk \( -regex 'all/[^/]+/\.(ssh.*|sync)' -prune -o -exec rm {} + \)

$: find all
all
all/mainfolder
all/mainfolder/.ssh
all/mainfolder/.ssh/authorized_keys
all/mainfolder/.ssh/id_rsa
all/mainfolder/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
all/mainfolder/.sync
all/mainfolder/test
all/mainfolder/test/.ssh
```

This still leaves some empty directories, so to clean those up in a quick second pass:

```
$: find all -empty -type d -delete

$: find all
all
all/mainfolder
all/mainfolder/.ssh
all/mainfolder/.ssh/authorized_keys
all/mainfolder/.ssh/id_rsa
all/mainfolder/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
all/mainfolder/.sync
```

I think that leaves the result you wanted.
Please backup and/or test before running it locally.
I recommend using `echo` and `\;` instead of `+` for testing, as you can see the files better;

```
$: find all -mmin +2 -type f \( -regextype awk -regex 'all/[^/]+/\.(ssh.*|sync)' -prune -o -exec echo rm {} \; \)
rm all/mainfolder/.file2
rm all/mainfolder/file1
rm all/mainfolder/test/.file4
rm all/mainfolder/test/.ssh/.file6
rm all/mainfolder/test/.ssh/file5
rm all/mainfolder/test/file3
```

The `+` is a lot more efficient for a live run, so if the actual filesystem is bigger it's probably worth switching it back.

```
$: find all -mmin +2 -type f \( -regextype awk -regex 'all/[^/]+/\.(ssh.*|sync)' -prune -o -exec echo rm {} + \)
rm all/mainfolder/.file2 all/mainfolder/file1 all/mainfolder/test/.file4 all/mainfolder/test/.ssh/.file6 all/mainfolder/test/.ssh/file5 all/mainfolder/test/file3
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to do what you want is to use Bash pathname expansion (aka globbing) to exclude files and directories and `find` to process the unexcluded paths.  Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean Bash code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

shopt -s dotglob extglob nullglob

find all/*/!(.sync|.ssh) -type f -mmin +2 -print
```

- `shopt -s ...` enables some Bash settings that are required by the code:

  - `dotglob` enables globs to match files and directories that begin with `.`.  `find` processes such files by default.
  - `extglob` enables "extended globbing" (including patterns like `!(.sync|.ssh)`).  See the [extglob](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) section in [glob - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob).
  - `nullglob` makes globs expand to nothing when nothing matches (otherwise they expand to the glob pattern itself, which is almost never useful in programs).
- Add `-delete` to the `find` options if you are happy that it will delete only the files that you want deleted.

Comment: `find all/*/!(.sync|.ssh)` would also delete the all/mainfolder/.ssh folder and files in it but i only want to delete e.g. all/mainfolder/folder/.ssh. How can i fix that?

Comment: @sangul, `find all/*/!(.sync|.ssh)` excludes `all/mainfolder/.ssh` (and possible others like `all/anotherfolder/.ssh`).  It won't be deleted by `find` , and neither will anything under it.  That's what the `!` in the pattern means.  If the code in the answer is producing unexpected output please let me  know exactly what it is and I will try to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Per your specification:

- keep `./all/mainfolder/.ssh` and its content
- keep `./all/mainfolder/.sync`
- delete other **files** (not directories) that are older than 2 minutes

You can try:

```
find ./all/mainfolder -type f ! -path './all/mainfolder/.ssh/*' \
  ! -path ./all/mainfolder/.sync -mmin +2 -delete
```

Or, if your `find` is GNU `find`:

```
find ./all/mainfolder -type f ! -regex '\./all/mainfolder/\.\(ssh/.*\|sync\)' \
  -mmin +2 -delete
```

If you want to delete files **and directories**:

```
find ./all/mainfolder -mindepth 1 ! -path ./all/mainfolder/.ssh \
  ! -path './all/mainfolder/.ssh/*' ! -path ./all/mainfolder/.sync -mmin +2 \
  -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Or, if your `find` is GNU `find`:

```
find ./all/mainfolder ! -regex '\./all/mainfolder\(/\.\(ssh\(/.*\)?\|sync\)\)?' \
  -mmin +2 -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i've tested it and these one would work for me (because i want to delete the files and directories): 


`find /all -mindepth 2 ! -regex '/all/mainfolder\(/\.\(ssh\(/.*\)?\|sync\)\)?' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf`

How i have to adjust the regex to process multiple mainfolders ? I tried the following, but it doesnt work -regex `/all/\*\(/\.\(ssh\(/.*\)?\|sync\)\)`